Downloading from Camera Roll
I am trying to download files from the camera roll of an attached iPhone using Swift, AppKit and the ImageCaptureCore framework.
It seems to work fairly well when the camera roll contains a relatively small number of files – like < 100 or so, however it becomes very slow and unreliable with a very large number – like 1500 (ie. doesn't successfully download all of the files or sidecar files).
I have also tried requesting the each item individually, then requesting the next item once that download has been completed, however that takes much, much longer with a large number of images, and seems to also not be reliable.
I would appreciate any suggestions or advice.
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import ImageCaptureCore

func downloadCameraItems() {
        guard let downloadLocation else { return }
        let cd = cameraDevice.camDevice
        let downloadOptions : [ICDownloadOption : Any] = [.downloadsDirectoryURL: downloadLocation, .overwrite: false, .sidecarFiles: true]
        
        cameraItems.forEach { ci in
            print("requesting download of \(ci.name ?? "")")
            if let filename = ci.name {
                let fileURL = downloadLocation.appendingPathComponent(filename)
                if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                    cd.requestDownloadFile(ci as! ICCameraFile, options: downloadOptions, downloadDelegate: self, didDownloadSelector: #selector(downloadItemCompleted), contextInfo: nil)
                    itemsRequested += 1
                } else {
                    print("Request: Skipping, file already exists: \(fileURL.path)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func downloadItemCompleted(
        _ file: ICCameraFile,
        error: Error?,
        options: [AnyHashable: Any]?,
        contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
    ) {
        print("*** Download: File downloaded - \(file.name ?? "")")
    }


If there are 1500 files your code will make 1500 concurrent download requests. Perhaps that's a bit too much. Maybe you need to refactor your code to request one at a time or no more than 10 (or some smaller number) at a time.

When I’ve made requests one at a time it seems as though it takes a very long time for the device to respond to the request and begin the download. The Image Capture app begins it almost immediately. I had thought it used the same framework.

I have no experience with what you are doing. I'm just making an observation. 1 at a time is probably too few. 1500 at a time is clearly too many. Try 10 or 25 or 50. Find what works best.

Is memory use increasing?

It appears to increase when dealing with more image files.

It appears as thought the number of files that eventually get downloaded is what I'm expecting to get and is reliable. However as the image count increases the download time does as well. On ~1800 images the associated sidecar files come in minutes after the main files are received.
I've tried sending a single request for download, then batches of 10 – waiting until the devices responds with the files before requesting another batch. In each case it seems as though the total time it takes to get all of the images is essentially the same.

How do you wait? Is downloading a few files slower than the Image Capture app?

With a smaller number of files – say <100 or so – the difference isn't very apparent. However it does take longer for the download to begin than it does using Image Capture. With Image Capture the files seem to begin downloading immediately, while with my application there is a delay before the delay before files begin coming in – a delay that is longer depending on image count.
Then, after the primary ICCamerFiles come in, there is another delay before the sidecar and associated files come in.

Have you tried Instruments? How do you wait, do you return to the main event loop?

I figured out the cause of my issue.
It was the way I was requesting thumbnails for the images that were to be downloaded. I need to revisit how I was handling that
